# BlackBerry How to set focus on screen load

Tags: blackberry

I am working on a screen where I have a list certain 10 fields(Horizontal field managers in Vertical field manager) as 10 rows. I want to set focus of ui after loading screen on the 4th row.

How can we do that such that when ever user open application focus is on 4 row.

Thanks

Comment: setFocus() usually does the trick.  What have you tried?

Comment: @Micheal- I have tried protected onUiEngineAttached(boolean attached) and I called the same in Main Screen constructor.But application failed.
I will try the one you have suggested. thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is quite old but i dont know why no one answered it. It is pretty straight forward. If you have a custom element the setFocus() may throw some errors but casting it to field or using the getField index will allow you call setFocus().

Field f = this.getField(2);
  f.setFocus();